# REST server endpoint to check if an authenticated user has access or permission to do an action

Tags: angularjs, rest, express

I have an Angular single page app where users can create a job listing. I want to control whether or not a user can edit a job listing. There are two roles that can edit a job listing. A authenticated user that can edit their own job listing or an administrator who can edit all job listings.

The server will test if a user has access to these actions. That is not a problem. However, before the state changes in the client app, I want to make a request to the server to check if the current logged in user has permission. So the request will check if a user can edit a job listing with #id 9de88893, for example.

What is that route look like. Does it only return true or false? I can't even imagine how this looks or how it would work. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the front end look like? Do you have a job listing page and then an edit button? You could hide the edit button if they don't have permission. You might also be able to create and register some middleware and attach it to some routes that you want to protect behind permissions.

Comment: [The repository is on GitHub](https://github.com/adam-s/simplejobs/blob/master/client/scripts/states/job/job.policies.js). I want a permission called editOwnJob which allows a user to edit a job listing they created. But, the check happens in the controller in the Angula app which doesn't seem the best place to put the logic. I'm thinking about creating an endpoint https://example.com/api/access?user=111userid111&permission=editOwnJob. I just want to know what developers usually do?

Answer (score 0):

I've made an angular 1.5.x startup project you can have a look at [this](https://github.com/muliyul/mean-seed-project/blob/master/bin/config/auth.js) (line 140).

In order to identify the user, you'll have to send the token with each request from the client (Angular).

The server validates the token and parses it (now knowing what user requested to alter the resource), then decides the course of action according to that user (since the token is encrypted with the server's secret).

The validation of access must be **ON THE SERVER SIDE** or else it is **NOT** secured!

Comment: The system already [has middleware on the server](https://github.com/adam-s/simplejobs/blob/master/server/routes/job.listings.routes.js) to check the user's roles and if access should be granted. I just want to protect the form on the client from accidentally being used. For example, how does StackOverflow prevent me from editing your profile on the client? Not just the server.

Comment: True. I misinterpreted your question. Regarding the question: if you don't have anything in the model (the user object) you can use to validate then yeah you're going to need to query the server in order to disable some UI element.

Comment: What does that look like? How does that endpoint function? What do people normally do?

Comment: Each job listing should have an owner field (list?) containing the id's of the owners. This lets you verify on the client whenever that user can enter the edit mode of that listing.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, and as Muli said above, authentication should be made on the server side. For security reasons.

Here's a tutorial that can guide you into how to make a token authentication system that works with angular.

> https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth

---

Ok, so, if I got it right, you're concerned that someone might force your front end...
Well, shit happens man. That's why you MUST allways validate on the server side each request.
As an example, I have a web app based on Angular and Laravel (As a restful service).
All, I mean ALL, requests are previously asked if the user is valid, before taking, changing or creating any row on DB.

In your possition, I'd use user roles on Angular side, and validate every request on the server side. You could make a function that check's if user's logged, and give it a flag to check user's permission.
If doesn't have access to that request, send back a 403 state response, and then show whatever alert you want on Angular side.
So, with user roles and states management, you can prevent users from landing on x page. And on the server side, prevent any forced attempt.

Front-end is easy to hack, that's a fact. That's why we validate allways on the server side.

Comment: The authentication is made on the server. I'm worried about authentication on the client so users don't accidentally end up on an edit page for a resource that the server will not let access to. I'm curious how to first check the server if the user has access before presenting a form to the user.

Comment: Go with roles. So the states will decide if the user logged can access x page... here's another tutorial...
http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/

Comment: You can establish user roles to filter wich routes can access each user depending on his/her's role

Comment: I'm using role based access. I've been using Drupal before switching to MEAN stack which has more fine grained access only allowing users to edit just the content they created with an authenticated role or all the content with an administrator role. It's kind of nice to get out the box. Regardless, I can't find any information about how to do this with Express and Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You might think in a different approach for that case.

**I assume:**

- I assume you know your logged user_id on the client sid;
- A user has a ROLE and an ID;

**Suggestion:**

- Add the Job owner (posting user_id) to your Job DTO (could be owner_id);
- Validate if a user is ADMIN or user_id == job.owner_id

Hope this helps in some way :)